# Get annotated methods from a specific class in java, with org.reflection

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I need to retrieve some annotated methods from various classes. I'm using this code:

```
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(
            new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("my.package"))
            .setScanners(new MethodAnnotationsScanner())
            );


    Set<Method> resources =
        reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(org.testng.annotations.Test.class);
```

I found the code for the Reflections class. However, this code is for the entire `package` (and with that said, for some reason the code returns all annotated methods in my project, and not just the specified package).

However, I just want to get the annotated methods from one specific class. I can't make heads or tails of the Reflections javadoc.

How can I change the constructor so that only the annotated methods from a specific class are returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to need to use an input filter to exclude other classes.  Here's an example (note: if there are any classes nested within MyClass those will get matched as well.)

```java
    final String className = MyClass.class.getCanonicalName();
    final Predicate<String> filter = new Predicate<String>() {
        public boolean apply(String arg0) {
            return arg0.startsWith(className);
        }
    };

    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(
            new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forClass(MyClass.class))
            .filterInputsBy(filter)
            .setScanners(new MethodAnnotationsScanner()));

    Set<Method> resources =
            reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(org.testng.annotations.Test.class);
```

Comment: I expanded on my explanation.  Is it more clear now?

Comment: Better but I still think your answer is wrong. When I run the code you propose, it returns methods from other classes.

Comment: Thank you, however when I run that, it returns the annotated methods of all the classes in my project, not just the specified class.

Comment: That'll teach me to post without testing.  I've corrected my solution to properly filter input classes.  This is working now on my end.

Comment: This still scans resources other than MyClass.class. Try printing out arg0 in the predicate and you'll see. Sure, the predicate will catch it, but it's unnecessarily considering classes other than MyClass.class